# How to write a generic Swift class function to initialize classes using a closure?

Tags: swift, generics, self, initializer

I'm trying to write a generic class function for Swift classes that would allow me to initialize classes using trailing closure syntax.

I have already got it working for specific classes, like for example UILabel.

```swift
// Extension for UILabel
extension UILabel {
    class func new(_ initialization: (inout UILabel) -> Void) -> UILabel {
        var label = UILabel()
        initialization(&label)
        return label
    }
}

// Initialize new UILabel using trailing closure syntax and "new" function
let label = UILabel.new {
    $0.textColor = .red
}
```

However, I want to have this functionality for all subclasses of NSObject, so I'm trying to implement a generic version of the "new" function above. So far I have come up with this:

```swift
extension NSObject {
    class func new(_ initialization: (inout Self) -> Void) -> Self {
        var newSelf = Self()
        initialization(&newSelf)
        return newSelf
    }
}
```

But this produces the following error: **'Self' is only available in a protocol or as the result of a method in a class; did you mean 'NSObject'?**

I am trying this in a playground with Swift 5.1 (Xcode 11 beta).

Comment: This can't work, because subclasses of `NSObject` have the ability to mark the `init` method as `NS_UNAVAILABLE`. So just because you have a meta type object of a class that extends `NSObject`, doesn't mean you can construct a new object of that type.

Comment: How about doing it only for UIView subclasses then? Would that be possible?

Comment: I would consider just defining something like `func with<T>(_ x: T, body: (inout T) throws -> Void) rethrows -> T { var x = x; try body(&x); return x }`. Then you can just say `let label = with(UILabel()) { ... }`. You then also have the flexibility to use whatever initialiser you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **Hamish** said, maybe it's better to leave the init outside so it is more flexible. However there could be a kind of workaround for this using a protocol.

```
protocol Initializable {
    init()
}

extension Initializable {
    static func new(_ initialization: (inout Self) -> Void) -> Self {
        var newSelf = Self()
        initialization(&newSelf)
        return newSelf
    }
}

extension NSObject: Initializable {}
```

`NSObject` already have an `init` so it automatically conforms to `Initializable`.
Then write your extension on the protocol.

The only thing to be aware is that you cannot use `class` modifier now, as you're in a `protocol`.

**Not sure if this can lead to problem for the `NS_UNAVAILABLE` modifier, I think it could crash at runtime when you use this on a class that is hiding the init.**

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot, that works very well! It does indeed crash at runtime when you use it with a subclass that marks `init` as unavailable, but that is fine for now. Just out of curiosity: How should I understand [this proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0068-universal-self.md) then? After reading this I thought it would be possible to use `Self` in a class, as I intended first.